# arreglos de string en C++

Tags: c++, array, string

Buenas ¿cómo puedo declarar un arreglo de 4 nombres?, algo asi:

*heroes[4] = {"magneto","ciclope","deadpool","profesor x"};* esta forma no me admite me marca error en el simbolo de igual.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    string maslargo, heroes[4];

    heroes[4] = {"deadpool", "ciclope", "magneto", "profesor charles xavier"};
   
    maslargo = largos(heroes);
    return 0;
}
```

El error me marca en el simbolo igual, recien estoy aprendiendo C++ y quizas sea un error muy simple pero no lo veo.
Si les sirve estoy usando Visual Studio code

Comment: Debería funcionar. Puedes compartir el error que te sale? [Dale aqui para editar tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/495611/edit).

Comment: Intenta buscar en google y conseguiras un codigo parecido a esto: `std::string str[4]={"...","/////","Cualquier pAlabra","otra mas"};`

Comment: @DanielBriceño Es C++, no seria `String`, seria `std::string`.

Comment: Si, me confundí con Java.

Comment: Procura agregar más partes del codigo, no queda del todo claro como se define heroes.

Answer (score 1):

En C++ un dato puede existir en tres estados:

1. **Declarado**: Le dices al compilador que el dato existe, sin entrar en detalles de cómo es.
2. **Definido**: Le das al compilador detalles de cómo es el dato.
3. **Inicializado**: Das valor al dato.

Esta expresión:

```
string maslargo, heroes[4];
```

Es la **definición** de dos tipos de datos distintos: el primero (`maslargo`) es un objeto de tipo `std::string` que ha sido inicializado por defecto, pues no se ha llamado a ningún constructor concreto. El segundo (`heroes[4]`) es una formación<sup>1</sup> de cuatro (`4`) objetos de tipo `std::string` y todos ellos están siendo inicializados por defecto pues no se llama a ningún constructor para crearlos.
Esta expresión:

```
heroes[4] = {"deadpool", "ciclope", "magneto", "profesor charles xavier"};
```

No es una declaración, ni una definición ni una inicialización. Dado que el dato `heroes` ya ha sido definido anteriormente, se trata de una asignación; concretamente estás intentando asignar una lista entre llaves al elemento que ocupa el índice `4` (que como las formaciones se indizan desde cero será [el quinto elemento](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119116/)), dejando de lado que ese elemento no existe, no puedes asignar una lista entre llaves a un elemento que no la acepta, seguramente querías hacer esto:

```
string maslargo;
vector<string> heroes; // vector, no formación.

heroes = {"deadpool", "ciclope", "magneto", "profesor charles xavier"};
```

---

###### <sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string maslargo = "";
    std::string heroes[4] = { "deadpool","ciclope","magneto","profesor_charles_xavier" };

    maslargo = largos(heroes);
    return 0;
}
**texto en negrita**
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Por favor describa la explicación respuesta